# Visual Studio Azure build definition: what exactly is a 'Webspace'?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to setup a solution in Visual Studio Online to deploy to an Azure website. I've configured the website in Azure, downloaded the subscription file, and I'm now trying to figure out how to configure the build definition.

Most of this screen seems straightforward, but in section 6 (Deployment->Windows Azure Deployment Environment), I see two settings under 'Web site':

```
Web site name (fairly obvious)
Webspace (no idea what this is)
```

Underneath the Webspace field is a link called 'List of Geo Region and Webspace names', which gives a 404.

What do I provide here?

Comment: I believe it's just the region name, e.g `Australia East` (a list can be found at the bottom of this page: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/).  Is this the build preview?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition. After I disconnected and reconnected source control from Azure, I now have a new build definition that has 'northcentraluswebspace' as the Webspace, so I guess you're right. I still don't see these actual strings documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A webspace is just a logical container of sites inside a scale unit (selected automatically based on available capacity) in a geographical region. The API version used in VSO limits only one webspace per region (enforced through naming convention: Region + "webspace"). However you can use the following API to retrieve the existing webspaces for a given subscription: https://management.core.windows.net/{sub}/services/WebSpaces

Hope this helps - cheers